# how to loop array of array in angular? please show some method

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

i have array like this in ts file.

```
    let order : any[] = [
    [{order_id:1,order_name:"car"},{order_id:2,order_name:"honda car"},{order_id:3,order_name:"bmw car"}],
    [{order_id:4,order_name:"honda city car"}],
    [{order_id:5,order_name:"mercerdecescar"},],
    ]
```

how to display this type of data in angular using ngfor direactive

Comment: Working demo https://stackblitz.com/edit/array-demo-angular-2mktdd?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `*ngFor` twice.

```
<div *ngFor="let item of order">
  <div *ngFor="let o of item">
    {{o.order_name}}
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to print all those objects to your template you can first flat your matrix and convert to an one dimensional array, then you can apply *ngFor inside div or ng-container.

```js
order.flat(2)
```

```html
<ng-container *ngFor="let item of orders">
   {{ item.order_name }}
</ng-container>
```

If you want to print directly all your nested arrays, you can do something like this:

```html
<ng-container *ngFor="let order of orders">
  <div *ngIf="order.length > 1">
    <ng-container *ngFor="let item of order">
      {{ item.order_name}}
    </ng-container>
  </div>
  {{ order.order_name }}
</ng-container>
```